# how to connect to spsite with a credential information

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, credentials

I want to know how can I open an SPSite with credentials. These are my credentials:

```
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential();

                nc.Domain = "dm";
                nc.UserName = "user";
                nc.Password = "pass";
                string service = "http://serv:9111/";

            CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
            myCache.Add(new Uri(service), "NTLM", nc);
```

and I didn't find the way to open my site:

```
using (SPSite site1 = new SPSite() )
                {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, SPWeb and SPSite objects are not remotable, the code using the API's needs to run on the SharePoint Server, meaning that the code will run under the current user's credentials and permissions, unless you enclose your code in a RunWithElevatedPrivileges block. In this case, the code will run under the Application Pool identity, which has site collection administrator privileges on all site collections hosted by that application pool.

**UPDATE:**

In order to connect to a different farm, you need to use the C# CSOM.

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://yourserver/")) {
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: in fact I want to connect to another siteServer(another farm ), how can I proceed ? thanks

Comment: You must use the SharePoint C# CSOM. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094(v=office.14).aspx